# Create or replace a stored procedurein SQL with parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I want write a structure of a query to create or replace a stored procedure called UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE that takes a in_School_ID parameter as an integer and a in_Leader_Score parameter as an integer by using the #SET TERMINATOR statement to use the @ for the CREATE statement terminator. I have a table named SCHOOLS who have several columns such as School_ID, Leaders_score, etc. Here is my code:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE( 
IN IN_SCHOOL_ID INTEGER, IN IN_Leader_Score INTEGER )       -- Name of this stored procedure routine

LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA                      
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1               

BEGIN 

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR             
    WITH RETURN FOR                 
    
    SELECT school_id ,Leaders_score
    FROM SCHOOLS;
    OPEN C1;
END
@
```

the problem is that I'm not sure for the part between Begin and End, could someone help?

Comment: What tool do you use to run it? What error do you get?

Comment: I used DB2 Cloud, I have error like this : 
The signature provided in the definition for routine "KLS36797.UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE" matches the signature of some other routine.. SQLCODE=-454, SQLSTATE=42723, DRIVER=4.27.25

Comment: This means, that you already have a routine with the same name and a number of parameters. If you want to overwrite existing routine definition use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks very much, but I have another question, why would we create these two parameters? because in my table 'Schools', these integer variables 'school_id', 'Leaders_score' exists already, sorry, I'm a new one in the stored procedre.

Comment: Don't call table columns as "variables". Routine parameters, local variables and table columns are different entities not related to each other. Parameter use is as in whatever other programming language - if you need it, then you use it. You don't use routine parameters according to the routine body above. So, it's question to you - why you defined them at all...